# How to add and push empty directory in git?

Tags: git, github

When I run `git status` git doesn't show the empty directory.
My remote repository is in github.
Can't I add and push empty directory?

Answer (score 4):

The usual way to force adding an empty directory in systems that ignores empty directories is to add a hidden file in each such directory:

```
$ touch directoryname/.empty_dir
$ git add directoryname/.empty_dir
$ git push
```

With `git`, you may choose to use `.gitignore` in place of `.empty_dir` above (really, any name will do, and the only reason to use a *hidden* filename is to avoid seeing it when you list the directory's contents with `ls`).

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to. But you can always add an empty `readme.md` or `.gitignore` to be able to do so.

See https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux / MAC OSX, use the following one-liner, to create / put empty placeholder files into the folders, recursively, to prevent them from getting ignored, by git:

```
find . -type d -empty -not -path "./.git/*" -exec touch {}/.gitkeep \;
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: To make it not even enter `./.git`: `find . -path ./.git -prune -o -type d -empty -exec touch {}/.gitkeep \;`